# Projecting the rectangle onto the plane

Tags: calculus

Find the area of the parallelogram obtained by projecting the rectangle $(0,0,0),(0,1,0),(2,0,0),(2,1,0)$ onto the plane $x + 4y - 5z = 4$ along $\vec{i} + \vec{j} + \vec{k}$

Now, first I don't understand the question. How does one project a rectangle onto the plane along some vector ? What is happening here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a line through each corner of the rectangle in the given direction.  You are to find where that line hits the given plane.  The four intersection points will define a parallelogram in the plane and you are to find its area.

The line through $(2,1,0)$ and parallel to $\vec{i} + \vec{j} + \vec{k}$ can be parameterized as $(2+t,1+t,t)$.  Find the $t$ where it hits the plane, then the point of intersection.  Do the same for the other three corners.

Comment: Thanks Ross, makes sense now.

Comment: But for point $(0,0,0)$, vector parallel to the given vector and passing through this point would be $<t,t,t>$ and when we plug the components in the equation of the plane, we get $t + 4t - 5t = 4$ which is $0=4$. Something am I doing wrong ?

Comment: As I understand the problem, you are doing fine.  The difficulty is that the vector is parallel to the plane, so you can't do the projection I suggested.  Either the problem setter made a mistake or I have not understood the question correctly.  I suggest you unaccept my answer (click on the check mark again) and maybe somebody else will have a better idea.

Comment: I will check with the person who gave the problem, Thanks again Ross